# Category posts not displaying within WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress site is not displaying posts under Categories. If I go to

http://example.com/category/news/

I see the appropriate header, but no posts are displayed. I activated a different theme and am able to see the posts correctly, which means the problem lies within my theme.

I'm curious the best way to debug where the problem is?

Comment: This is pretty open ended.  Is it a custom theme?  The best way would be to (likely) go into your `archive.php` template, and start debugging there.  If you shared that code with us, we might be able to get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, @cale_b. It is a custom theme that I was not involved with developing. I've never created a theme from scratch, so this is new to me. I'll take a look at the archive file. Appreciate it.